# How to shrink a ScrollView's height keeping the other view(Button) fixed in place?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` and a `Button` side by side in a vertical orientation(*both children of `ConstraintLayout`'s weighted chain with weight 1 and 0 respectively for `ScrollView` and the `Button`. BTW, you can optionally assume them to be children of a `LinearLayout` instead of a `ConstraintLayout` because a weighted `ConstraintLayout` chain works almost the same as a `LinearLayout`*).

This is one of those typical use cases where you create the `ScrollView` with a list of certain items(children) and at the bottom have a big Button that searches your database based on the values filled in the `ScollView` children. Something like below:

[image]

The red-color encircled portion is where the Button is supposed to be(it is there but not visible).

Now the problem.

I want the button to be visible at all times irrespective of the `ScrollView`(*if that implies shrinking of `ScrollView`'s height, so be it because it is scrollable after all*) but since the contents of `ScrollView` take enough space to hide the `Button`, by default it gets hidden. The solution(I think) would entail having to shrink the `ScrollView`'s height just the amount that the `Button` is visible in the remaining space below.

Note that, I don't want the arrangement to end up like having the `Button` overlay the `ScrollView`'s area. This is the case where no shrinkage of height would be required to `ScrollView` but rather the `Button` is made to float above it at the bottom, hiding some of its area. I want to force the `ScrollView` to adjust to the `Button`. Also, having weights of 1 and 0 respectively didn't help.

**EDIT:** Code for layout. (The `Button` is with id search_button)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/search_button"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:id="@+id/frameLayout">

                <include layout="@layout/layout_subject_search" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/view" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view">

                <include layout="@layout/layout_qualification_search" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/view2" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/search_by_location_label"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/location_toggle_switch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/map_search_fragment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="240dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/location_toggle_switch"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

            </FrameLayout>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/search_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="@string/search_tutors_string"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView2" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/search_tutors_progress_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**EDIT 2:** As asked by @marshmallow 's,

// include layout="@layout/layout_subject_search"

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/search_by_subject_label"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>

    <com.learncity.learner.search.SubjectMultiAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/subject_multi_auto_complete_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:ems="10"/>

</merge>
```

// include layout="@layout/layout_qualification_search"

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/search_by_qualification_label"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>

    <com.learncity.learner.search.QualificationMultiAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/qualification_multi_auto_complete_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:ems="10"/>


</merge>
```

Comment: Please share the relevant code

Comment: @maRShmallow : Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thanks to @marshmallow for suggesting the `wrap_content` strategy as well as repeatedly testing and replying with updated solutions.

---

The solution is bit of a twist on his suggestion:

- Make `layout_height` for `Button` to be `wrap_content`. Why? We want to *declare* button's height as a reference for `ScrollView` to adjust its size and the true height of the button is obtained by using `wrap_content`.
- Now, we want to tell the `ScrollView` to adjust its size as per button. To do this, we use `layout_height` as `0dp` which translates to, *"Use available constraints to adjust your size rather than asserting any fixed size of your own"*. For the same reason, `Button`'s height is not 0dp.
- Next, we establish a weighted chain relationship between the two with weight of 1 for `ScrollView` and 0 for `Button`(it doesn't effectively work for Button because width is not 0dp/match constraints; so just a pointer to `ScrollView` to take up space remaining other than `Button`)

With this, the final solution becomes:(*The solution tested for both portrait and landscape modes*)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/search_button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <include layout="@layout/layout_subject_search" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view">

                <include layout="@layout/layout_qualification_search" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout1" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="@string/search_by_location_label"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/location_toggle_switch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text=""
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/map_search_fragment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="240dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/location_toggle_switch"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

            </FrameLayout>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/search_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="@string/search_tutors_string"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="0" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/search_tutors_progress_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `ScrollView` height to `wrap_content`

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    ...>
</ScrollView>
```

Also change `constraintVertical_bias` to 0.0 in ScrollView

```
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
```

**Update:**

Change height to `Button` to `wrap_content` and it will be displayed properly.

Comment: I tried it. Not working :(. I can only see the ScrollView covering the entire screen and Button hidden where it was.

Comment: Can you add code for included layouts? Because without including those layouts and with my suggested changes it is working fine

Comment: Added in EDIT 2.

Comment: Check updated answer, you will have to add appropriate margins though

Comment: I checked. This one results in a floating Button. Margins didn't solve it either. Maybe, Constraint Layout is not the way to go...

Comment: Yes, because it is aligned to bottom of parent it will float when soft keyboard is visible.

Comment: I have added a final solution as a twist to your suggestion. Thank you very much for spending time on the problem.